# Send Two Ints Between Arduino Boards Every .1 Seconds

Tags: arduino

I have a desire to connect two seperate arduino boards in order to send 2 integres from one to another.

So from board number 1 I would like to send two integres each ranging from -15000 to 15000 to board number 2.

So any suggestions how to do it?
I looked up at many ways such as I2C or stuff like that but i never managed to get a simple code out of it just sending two integres.

The other problem is the speed. How fast I need it to send. I need it to change at speed of 0.1 seconds on the board number 2. So every 0.1 seconds new value of int.

It's that even possible?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably to use a serial interface with some standard Arduino functions. Theres a thing called software serial, which is ideal, because you can keep the hardware serial connected to your terminal to read out the data.

Check out: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

All you need is a wire or two, and don't forget to connect the grounds of both Arduino's to eachother.

Lukas